# Dynamic Memory Allocation of Vectors in C++

Tags: c++

I need to write a function that adds the elements of two 3D arrays, stores the result in a third 3D array, takes the results and copies them into a one dimensional vector, then returns this vector by constant reference. The problem I am having is how to use dynamic memory allocation to return the vector since you cannot return a local variable. This is what the code looks like if you COULD return a local variable:

```
template <class T>
const vector<T>& allOperations(T*** const &x, T*** const &y, T*** &z, int height, int width, int depth)
{
    vector<T> results(height*width*depth);

    // Add the values of array x and y
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < depth; k++)
            {
                z[i][j][k] = x[i][j][k] + y[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }

    int l = 0;
    //Places the values of array z into a vector 
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < depth; k++)
            {
                results[l] = z[i][j][k];
                l++;
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Here is my incorrect attempt at using dynamic memory allocation:

```
template <class T>
const vector<T>& allOperations(T*** const &x, T*** const &y, T*** &z, int height, int width, int depth)
{
    vector<T>* results(height*width*depth) = new vector<T>;

    // Add the values of array x and y
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < depth; k++)
            {
                z[i][j][k] = x[i][j][k] + y[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }

    int l = 0;
    //Places the values of array z into a vector 
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < depth; k++)
            {
                *results[l] = z[i][j][k];
                l++;
            }
        }
    }
    return *results;
}
```

Comment: All STL container content is automatically stored on the heap, so you can simply return `vector<T>` without memory overhead. `const` shouls also work. Not tried it yet though. I was told that you should not use STL containers in conjunction with dynamic memroy allocation out of two reasons. First : code gets incredibly messy, esp. for multidimensional arrays. Second : it's kinda double work as containers located on the stack just store the reference on the local function stack and everything else is created on the heap for you.

Comment: Would this be homework by any chance? If so, it would explain the bizarre requirement that a newly created vector be returned by constant reference.

Answer (score 2):

It does not make sense to return a reference to a local variable.  If you resort to your second solution (return a reference to a `new`'d vector), then you will almost certainly have a memory leak.  By convention, obtaining a reference usually means some other entity is already managing the returned object's lifetime.

There are multiple things you can do to work around this problem.

---

Don't perform dynamic memory allocation, change the function signature.

```
// Return a copy of the vector.
vector<T> allOperations(T*** const &x, T*** const &y, T*** &z, int height, int width,  int depth)
{
    vector<T> results(height*width*depth);
    // ...
    return results;
}
```

If you compiler performs [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) and/or supports [C++11 move constructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors), the "copy" will never take place and the return will be very efficient.

---

If you really want to dynamically allocate the vector to satisfy some other constraint, you also need to change the function signature:

```
// Return a pointer to a newly allocated vector.
const vector<T>* allOperations(T*** const &x, T*** const &y, T*** &z, int height, int width, int depth)
{
    vector<T>* results(height*width*depth) = new vector<T>;
    // ...
    return results;
}
```

If you do so, consider returning a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) instead of returning a bare pointer.

---

If this is a member function, then perhaps you can store the vector inside the object.

```
template<typename T>
class SomeClass
{
    std::vector<T> results;
public:
    // ...

    // Modify member and return reference to internal member.
    const vector<T>& allOperations(T*** const &x, T*** const &y, T*** &z, int height, int width,  int depth)
    {
        results.resize(height*width*depth);
        // ...
        return results;
    }
};
```

---

Another possible, but *strongly discouraged* solution is to return a reference to some global variable.

```
std::vector<T> results;

// Modify global and return reference to global variable.
const vector<T>& allOperations(T*** const &x, T*** const &y, T*** &z, int height, int width,  int depth)
{
    results.resize(height*width*depth);
    // ...
    return results;
}
```

Or, in its disguised (but exactly equivalent) form:

```
// Modify global and return reference to global variable.
const vector<T>& allOperations(T*** const &x, T*** const &y, T*** &z, int height, int width,  int depth)
{
    // Global variable with name not visible outside the function.
    static std::vector<T> results;

    results.resize(height*width*depth);
    // ...
    return results;
}
```

Comment: The function must return a constant reference, not just the variable. That is why I must dynamically allocate the vector. Your second example returns a pointer to a newly allocated vector, but what should the code look like if I want to return a reference to a newly allocated vector?

Comment: @user1205613: You do realize, I hope, that the vector that was dynamically allocated within the function, will have to be deleted *outside* the function as some point, or else you'll get a memory leak.

Comment: @user1205613: You syntaxically *can* return a constant reference to a `new`'d vector, but you should *never* do that because the caller will not "own" the memory.  If your `allOperations()` function is actually an object method, then you can have the object own the vector, but this does not seem to be the case.  Your requirements, as stated, are ill-defined.  You want the function to return a reference to an existing object and you also want the same function to create an object.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user1205613: There's something you're not telling us.  Why *must* it return a const reference?  Is this an assignment of some kind?  What imposes the type of the return value?