# Safe to return a vector populated with local variables?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, scope

Is it safe to return a vector that's been filled with local variables?

For example, if I have...

```
#include <vector>

struct Target
{
public:
    int Var1;
    // ... snip ...
    int Var20;
};


class Test
{
public:
    std::vector<Target> *Run(void)
    {
        std::vector<Target> *targets = new std::vector<Target>;
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            Target t = Target();
            t.Var1 = i;
            // ... snip ...
            t.Var20 = i*2; // Or some other number.
            targets->push_back(t);
        }
        return targets;
    }


};

int main()
{
    Test t = Test();
    std::vector<Target> *container = t.Run();

    // Do stuff with `container`
}
```

In this example, I'm creating multiple `Target` instances in a for loop, pushing them to the vector, and returning a pointer to it.  Because the `Target` instances were allocated locally, to the stack, does that mean that the returned vector is unsafe because it's referring to objects on the stack (that may soon be overwritten, etc)?  If so, what's the recommended way to return a vector?

I'm writing this in C++, by the way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Memory Allocation of Vectors in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252523/dynamic-memory-allocation-of-vectors-in-c)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Elements get copied when you `push_back` them into a vector (or assign to elements). Your code is therefore safe – the elements in the vector are no references to local variables, they are owned by the vector.

Furthermore, you don’t even need to return a pointer (and *never* handle raw pointers, use smart pointers instead). Just return a copy instead; the compiler is smart enough to optimise this so that no actual redundant copy is made.

Comment: I wouldn't say never handle raw pointers - everything has it's place. However, returning by value not causing a copy is now official thanks to the new C++11 standard and move constructors.

Comment: @carleeto : It's been official for years with (N)RVO.

Comment: I stopped bothering with returning pointers since RVO in GCC 3.1 :) However, *"never handle raw pointers"*? I'd go with carleeto on this one and disagree with you, they have their uses. But hey, +1 anyway.

Comment: @carleeto If you know what you’re doing, raw pointers have their place. But even then, legitimate uses are *excessively* rare. And a raw pointer in conjunction with `new` is *always* wrong: who owns the memory? As long as you use raw pointers as *weak pointers*, i.e. without any claim of ownership, that’s OK. But it’s not what the OP is doing. A raw pointer is never appropriate in such a  case.