# Valgrind complains of invalid read when accessing struct member through pointer to struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, valgrind

The struct is defined as such:

```
struct section_{
    int start;
    ...
};
```

For reasons I will not go into, I need to pass a pointer to the struct to a function that accepts a `void*`. The function looks like this:

```
void* my_fun(void* sec){
    section_* section = (section_*)sec;
    int start = section->start; // <---- valgrind complains here
    ...
}
```

I have a `std::vector<section_*>` and I need to call `my_fun` on each of the elements of this vector. I do this like so:

```
std::vector<section_*> sections = get_sections();
for (int i = 0; i < sections.size(); ++i){
    my_fun((void*)sections[i]);
}
```

The `get_sections()` function looks something like:

```
std::vector<section_*> get_sections(){
    std::vector<section_*> sections;
    section_ sec1;
    sec1.start = 0;
    ...
    sections.push_back(&sec1);
    return sections;
}
```

I've tracked the problem down to the line in `my_fun` that says

```
int start = section->start;
```

The error says:

```
==3512== Invalid read of size 4
==3512==    at 0x41A970: my_fun(void*)
...
==3512==  Address 0xffeffa2a0 is on thread 1's stack
==3512==  14160 bytes below stack pointer
```

Even though I'm getting an invalid  read, I am still able to access the members of the struct inside `my_fun` and they are the correct values. Why is that?

I realize that this code is in little bits and pieces, but the actual code is much more complex and lengthy than what I'm showing, though I think I'm showing all the relevant parts. I hope the info I gave is enough.

Comment: did you try using [static_casting](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/), It looks like a casting problem.

Comment: @Vtik I've never used that before... I will look into that. Thanks

Comment: This `sections.push_back(&sec1); return sections;` returns a pointer to a local variable. Like the message says *==3512==  Address 0xffeffa2a0 is on thread 1's stack*

Comment: @Vtik I did `section_* section = static_cast<section_*>(sec);`, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @BoPersson, you add a local variable to the vector:

```
std::vector<section_*> get_sections(){
    std::vector<section_*> sections;
    section_ sec1;    // <- Local, temporary variable 
    sec1.start = 0;
    ...
    sections.push_back(&sec1); // <- Address of local var
    return sections;
    // When this function ends, sec1 is no longer valid
}
```

You can either use `new` to create `sec1` (`delete`ing it later). Or change the vector type to `std::vector<section_> sections;`.

Comment: Also, why was I able to access the struct members (giving the correct values) if `sec1` was no longer valid?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So, if I change the vector type to std::vector<section_> sections, I can pass &sections[i] to my_fun, yes?

Comment: You were just getting lucky. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/669576) might help.

Comment: Just changed my code and ran it. This fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I consider it very **un**lucky that the program appeared to work as intended.

Comment: @user2079303 Agreed. A hidden bug that might show itself later is not lucky.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  I guess push_back copies the contents of the variable into the vector, so adding a local variable to the vector should not be a issue right? Could you please clarify. Ref: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304480/safe-to-return-a-vector-populated-with-local-variables)

Comment: @Shyam The problem here is the OP is adding a pointer to a local var. If you are not doing that, you should be ok.

Comment: ah! got it. Thanks @JohnnyMopp